# Export variable containing special characters(args)

Tags: linux, bash

I want to export CELERY_ARGS

`CELERY_ARGS="--prefetch-multiplier=1 --loglevel=info --concurrency=1"`

But when I export, I get the following issue.

```
export $CELERY_ARGS
bash: export: --: invalid option
export: usage: export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
```

Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: You export names, not values.

Comment: More generally, you use `$` to *get the value* of a variable, never when setting a variable or its properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting isn't something you do with a value; it's something you do to a *name*.

```
export CELERY_ARGS
```

adds `CELERY_ARGS` to a list of variable names (if it isn't already there) whose values should be added to the environment of a child process when it is started.

Note that this means it doesn't matter what the value of `CELERY_ARGS` is when you export the name (or even if the variable is defined yet); the value received by the child process is the value at process creation.

For example,

```
$ printenv bar
$ bar=7
$ printenv bar
$ export bar
$ bar=9
$ printenv bar
9
```